# tag mp3 files from filename recursively batch file

Tags: batch-file, mp3

I have this batch file to tag my mp3s from there file name, how do i make it  recursive so it picks up all mp3 files in different directories

```
TAG.exe --remove --auto --scheme "A - T+L+Y" --rename "T" C:\music\*.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r "c:\music" %%D in (.) do TAG.exe --remove --auto --scheme "A - T+L+Y" --rename "T" "%~fD\*.mp3"
```

Double the percents if used within a batch file.